# "TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable" after submitting form, while rendering template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to make an auctions app where as part of the app, users can place bids by submitting the BidForm.

In `views.py`:

```py
def listing_page(request, listing_id):
    listing_selected = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
    form = BidForm()
    bids = []
    winning = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        person = Person.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(watchlist=listing_selected)
    else: 
        person = False    
    if listing_selected.current_bid:
        bids = Bid.objects.filter(listing=listing_selected)
        if listing_selected.current_bid.user == request.user:
            winning = True
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BidForm(request.POST)
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        # render template with error message
        if form.is_valid():
            bid = Bid()
            bid.user = request.user
            bid.listing = listing_selected
            bid.amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']
            bid.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Bid placed successfully.')
            return render(request, "auctions/listing_page.html", context={
                "listing": listing_selected,
                "person": person,
                "num_bids": len(bids) + 1,
                "winning": winning,
                'form': form,
                'messages': messages
            })
    else:   
        return render(request, "auctions/listing_page.html", {
            "listing": listing_selected,
            "person": person,
            "num_bids": len(bids),
            "winning": winning,
            'form': form
        })
```

When I submit the bid form, I get this error:

```sh
Error during template rendering
    In template C:\Users\SJEOM\Documents\cs50_web\commerce\commerce\auctions\templates\auctions\layout.html, error at line 0
  File "C:\Users\SJEOM\Documents\cs50_web\commerce\commerce\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\SJEOM\Documents\cs50_web\commerce\commerce\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SJEOM\Documents\cs50_web\commerce\commerce\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", 
    line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SJEOM\Documents\cs50_web\commerce\commerce\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\SJEOM\Documents\cs50_web\commerce\commerce\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
C:\Users\SJEOM\Documents\cs50_web\commerce\commerce\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render
    values = list(values) 
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

What does this error mean? Where should I be looking? Thank you.

In `layout.html`:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Auctions{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Auctions</h1>
        <div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                Signed in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.
            {% else %}
                Not signed in.
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Active Listings</a>
            </li>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'create' %}">Create Listing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
        <hr>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: `layout.html` pasted as requested.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Edit: I found the problem code, in `listing_page.html`. Once I get rid of this code, or instead of looping through messages in a for loop just put `{{  messages  }}`, it no longer shows the error.

```html
{% if messages %}
   <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{  message  }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your code in views.py is probably working correctly, as it tries to render your page. The error probably is in your template \templates\auctions\layout.html. Could you paste it? It says that you are trying to loop something that does not accept loops.

Comment: Sure, I added the requested code.

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka You were right, once I got rid of the for loop in the template, it worked. I added the for loop code in the original post. What's wrong with it? How can I display the messages correctly?

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka Fixed! I had to get rid of "messages": messages in the context. That was passing in the messages module, instead of the messages iterable. Turns out the messages iterable is available in the template without passing it in the context. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I was just going to reply that. Great that you found the solution. messages in views.py is an object and you can't iterate in the template like a list.